# How to get value of a selected option from select tag and use it in WP_query to filter posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, theme-development, custom-field, search

This is how I'm getting the value but how to use it in WP_Query so when I click Search to display let's say posts with Option 1 value?

I'm doing this but don't know if meta_value is the answer

```
$search_query=new Wp_Query($search_args);
$something=isset($_GET['something'])&&$_GET['something']?$_GET['something']:'';

    if($something){
         $search_args['meta_value']=$something;
    }

<select name="something" id="" class="" 
style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="Something">Something</option>
            <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have posts with custom fields that have your select fields values as values for these custom fields, in this case you should take a closer look in **'Custom Fields Paramenters'** from the WP_Query class references at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters doing so you can just compare you select fields values with your post custom fields using the several relations possibles. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I was going to do what you suggested but was in doubt,I just needed to hear it from someone else that,that is the choice.